# why do these two expressions behave differently when the only difference is the values?

Tags: javascript, expression, behavior

Put simply my question is:

If I try `0.1+0.2!==0.3` in javascript, it will return `TRUE`. But for `0.1+0.3!==0.4`, it will return `FALSE`. 
Why?

When I searched on google I found that the javascript engine uses IEEE 754 format for floating point numbers. It does not have a concept of an integer.

Why does it behave differently in the two examples, above?

Comment: Not sure if it is the same in JavaScript but in many languages decimal variables are not reliable for comparison. The reason is that the binary way of representing a decimal, as used by many languages, implies some lack of precision.

Comment: @Johnride's comment is correct, I found that article a good read (although its a designer Magazine): http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/05/30/10-oddities-and-secrets-about-javascript/ (it's explained under Miscellaneous)

Comment: what exactly are the -2's for? You could at least add a comment. God the secretive downvoters bug me. How is anyone supposed to improve their question if you never say why you're downvoting them? grr